# The use of a semicolon in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So what is the use of the semicolon (`;`) in python? All it does is separate multiple statements. I can't seem to find any practical use for the semicolon. If you are going to use a semicolon, then why not just put the multiple statements on multiple lines? If you want to define multiple variables on one line, you could always do: `x, y = 0, 1` or something along those lines. The only time I can find a use for this is if you are using the terminal and you want to execute a command in python (for instance: `python3 import random; print(random.randint(1, 10))`). Even now, you can always use the python shell with `python3` and then execute the code you want. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could show me a practical example of a semicolon.

Thanks!

Comment: You already answered your own question: *"if you are using the terminal and you want to execute a command in python"*

Comment: You've pretty much described the use-case, putting several simple statements on one line. I rarely, if ever, use it. Only sometimes when I use `python -c "<statement>;<statements>...;<statement>"`

Comment: Feel free not to use it.

Comment: It's seldom used in production code, except for occasionally when someone is try to write a "one-liner". Generally is decreases readability IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically just denotes separation and is a leftover from older programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

see example usage in book: *Python Data Science Handbook*

```
plt.plot(x, y ,'o', color = 'black');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).